# How to prove that $x^4+x^3+x^2+3x+3 $ is irreducible over ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, computational-algebra

Which criterion (test) one can use in order to prove that  $x^4+x^3+x^2+3x+3 $ is irreducible over ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers ?

Neither of  [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) and [Cohn's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion) cannot be applied on this polynomial. I know that one can use [factor](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20x%5E4%2bx%5E3%2bx%5E2%2b3x%2b3) command in Wolfram Alpha and show that polinomial is irreducible but that isn't point of this question.

Comment: Is semi brute force OK? If so, there is an easy argument. It actually doesn't care very much about the coefficient of $x$, as long as integer root is avoided.

Comment: @AndreNicolas,Actually I would like to know if there is some good computational-algebra algorithm

Comment: @There are good canned procedures for computing Galois groups. Overkill, probably.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let your polynomial be $f$. Clearly it has no linear factor, since it has no root in $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence if it factors, it factors as the product of two irreducible quadratics $f_1, f_2$.

Now looking mod $2$ we get a factorization $f=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=f_1f_2$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. Now since $f$ has no root mod $2$,  $f_1$ and $f_2$ are also irreducible quadratics in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. But the only irreducible quadratic in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is $x^2+x+1$. This would imply $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = (x^2+x+1)^2$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, which is false.

Comment: +1 Another way of seeing that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $F_2[x]$ is to observe that it is a factor of $(x^5-1)=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$. Thus any zero would a root of unity of order five. But $q=16$ is the lowest power of two with the property that $5\mid q-1$, so those roots of unity live in $GF(16)$. Thus their primitive polynomial has to be quartic. Your solution may be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If a quartic is reducible it has either a linear factor or a quadratic factor. It is easy to check that your polynomial above has no linear solutions, and you can work out a contradiction if you assume that it can be factored into the product of two (monic) quadratics.